# Procedure to recreate changes to user permissions

Tags: stored-procedures, sap-ase

I encountered a problem yesterday. When I recreate a stored procedure which selects data from a view, the permissions have been revoked for view objects (like used tables in view) for all users except for the current user. For example;

The version of sybase ase is 12.5

Procedure;

```
drop proc testproc
go
create proc testproc
as 
begin 
....
    select * from testView
....
end
go
grant exec on testproc to public
go
```

View;

```
create view testView as
   select * from testTable
go
grant all on testView to public
go
```

And the error is

> SELECT permission denied on object 'testTable', database 'Mytest',
>   owner 'dbo'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're creating the view as DBO.
If testTable is DBO, why would you have your view belonging to another user?

Comment: the user who recreate the procedure is dbo.